# Cant register vNext DI services using generics

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

Before i moved to aspnet5/vNext i used SimpleInjector.  I could use SimpleInjector to register all my generic validators, using the following:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IValidator<>), new List<Assembly> { Assembly.Load("MY.OTHER.ASSEMBLY") });
```

My classes would be defined like this in my other assembly

```
public interface IMyInterface : IValidator<MyObject> {}

public class MyValidator : IMyInterface
{
   // Methods here
}
```

Is this possible to do using the standard vNext DI system?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Take a look here: http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2016/01/11/dependency-scanning-in-asp-net-5/

Comment: Good article, but it relies on your setting custom attributes on all classes.  Can you not do this without having to implement an attribute?  I know you can do it in AutoFac, but i dont want to include a DI framework to use 1 function

Comment: In ASP.NET 5 I always register everything manually, class by class. How many of such "registration lines" in code will you have? 5? 10? 20? Even if 20 then you could simply put this in separate method and still will be "clean".